# "The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old (found version 9000).", but I do actaully have installed version 10.1

Tags: python, pytorch

I was trying to check CUDA information on my Ubuntu device and I run `torch.cuda.current_device()`, and it errs:

```
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 17:14:51) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.current_device()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 377, in current_device
    _lazy_init()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 196, in _lazy_init
    _check_driver()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 110, in _check_driver
    of the CUDA driver.""".format(str(torch._C._cuda_getDriverVersion())))
AssertionError: 
The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old (found version 9000).
Please update your GPU driver by downloading and installing a new
version from the URL: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
Alternatively, go to: https://pytorch.org to install
a PyTorch version that has been compiled with your version
of the CUDA driver.
>>>
```

But I do have installed a higher version than 9.x:

```
>> nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Feb__8_19:08:17_PST_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.105
```

I wonder why this would happen and how I can solve this.

Comment: What is the output of `nvidia-smi`?

Comment: That's your cuda driver, not your nvidia gpu driver. Install a newer nvidia-driver by running: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa; sudo apt update; sudo apt install nvidia-driver-XXX` where X is a newer version of the drivers.